# Do i have to have both Droid and HTC to test my android app?

Tags: android

I have an android app for which i need to ensure that it has no design/interface issues on both Motorola Droid and HTC touch-screens.
Now my question is that do i have to have both devices available for testing? If not, then is there an alternate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is check that your activity layout looks good on both screens, I would say that testing on one of them is probably sufficient.  They are both hdpi devices, so Android should use the same resources when drawing the screens.

However, if you're wanting to do complete application-level testing, you probably need to test on both devices.  Given that a lot of HTC devices use Sense, there might be some slight differences in how it behaves (missing Intents for certain applications, etc).

In terms of getting access to both devices, I've heard good things about [Device Anywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/), but have never personally tried their service.

Comment: I'm having a problem with image placement.The placement is fine in HTC but when the user install the app in Droid then they get misplaced.
What should i do?